# backup SQL Server 2008 database on a network drive

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, backup

I need to backup my SQL Server 2008 database to another PC on network. I've even mapped network drive and assigned it another driver letter.

But when I try to select .bak file while exporting, only C: shows up. I've even restarted my SSMS.

Can somebody point out what else I may need to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can by using SQL

```
BACKUP DATABASE Foo TO DISK = '\\myserver\myshare\foo.bak' WITH INIT
```

Make sure the account used for the sql services has enough rights to write to the other pc.

---

For the reason the mapped network drives don't show up made with your user account. This has to do with the Sql Server *service* running under another user account then the one you've used for mapping the drive.

Comment: Thanks rdkleine, it worked! I had to change my SQL Service to my domain account from usual Network Service. 

However, it still does not show other drives in SSMS Backup.